# Netbeans 8.2 - Send email not working after Clean and Build

Tags: email, netbeans, jakarta-mail

this is making me crazy :) The code works great when i am coding on netbeans (i mean, it sends all emails i want with success) , **but, after Clean and Build, it just dont send any email.**

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz = my password

this is my sendig code:

```
private void envia_email (String email_selecionado) {

        String to = email_selecionado;
        String from = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp" );
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); //SSL Factory 
    try {    
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, "zzzzzzzzzzz");
                    }
                });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("EUROMILIONS PLAY SOFTWARE");
        message.setText(corpo_email.getText());
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        Transport.send(message);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mensagem enviada com sucesso !");
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        teste.setVisible(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Erro: "+ex.toString());
        //Logger.getLogger(serial_control.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

what can be wrong ? why it works on netbeans but not works after Clean and Build.

Thanks

Comment: Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: i found that it works on another computer.... cause i work in two diferent computers. well, in the computer it doesnt work, i get this debub from java:
.
.
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\tmp\si\FxJavaControlPanel-amd64_50470
basic: waiting connection
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg (O sistema não conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado)
.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with JavaMail.